# jQuery / CSS NOT selector, and stop () question

Tags: jquery, html, selector

Here is my site:

http://www.raceramps.com/v2

Move your mouse over the menu on the right side. Notice how Car Service, Trailer Hauling, and Show & Display are fully enlarged by default. This is because they are higher selling products, and most people who view this site are looking for those.

Currently there is an accordion menu setup using the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $( '.buttonEffectWrapper' ).hover (
        function () {

            var effect = $(this).siblings().filter(":last");
            effect.stop ().animate ( { opacity: 1}, { duration: 300 } );

            $(this).stop().parent().animate({height: "110px"}, {duration: 300 } );//accordion effect here


        },
        function () {
                    var effect = $(this).siblings().filter(":last");
                  effect.stop ().animate ( { opacity: 0}, { duration: 300 } );

                  $(this).stop().parent().animate({height: "30px"}, {duration: 300 } );//accordion effect here

        }
    );
} );
```

Firstly, if you move the mouse horizontally over one of the buttons several times, it builds a queue. I thought using stop() was supposed to fix this, but it doesn't seem to be.

Secondly, I don't want the first three divs (#car-service, #trailer-hauling, and #display-and-show) to collapse when the mouse leaves. I tried the following, but it selects *everything* else.

```
  $(this + ":not(#car-service, #trailer-hauling, #display-and-show)").stop().parent().animate({height: "30px"}, {duration: 300 } );
```

and thirdly, if you mouseover one div, and then move to one below it, as one div expands and the other collapses, your mouse ends up in a position you wouldn't intend. The only way I can think of to fix this is to not allow the previous div to collapse.

So if I moused over `#car-service`, then went to `#trailer-hauling`, `#car-service` shouldn't collapse. But If I move from `#trailer-hauling` to `#show-and-display`, then I want `#car-service` to contract. This should prevent the interface from being broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!$(this).is("#car-service, #trailer-hauling, #display-and-show")){
   $(this).parent().animate({height: "30px"}, {duration: 300, queue:false});
}
```

`$(this)` refers to a single element (or group of elements) in the DOM. I think it best to test whether it is/has a particular attribute or filter it, rather than playing with the `$(this)` selector.

Comment: @Jared, messed up the animate function. Also took @David's advice for the queue issue. It's fixed now. What was it doing for you?

Comment: I see... it's addressing (this), whereas it actually needs to look at the parent div. if(!$this).parent().is works.

Answer (score 0):

**first**
in the `animate()` second options argument, you can specify the queue:

```
effect.animate({
    opacity: 1
},{
    duration: 300,
    queue: false
});
```

**second**
Try this:

```
$(this).filter(function() {
    return !this.id.match(/^(car-service||trailer-hauling||display-and-show)$/);
}).someMethod()...
```

Comment: Thanks! First works, but the second makes it so none of them collapse any longer...